# Katakana that I can't get right

Tags: grammar, meaning, katakana

"渡辺さんってサブラの？" - what could this mean? Just can't catch the meaning of "サブラ". Help please.

Comment: Is there any sort of context you would like to share?

Comment: It was in the context of the dialogue: " - 渡辺さんは今どこにいるのかしら。 - 渡辺さんってサブラの？"

Answer (score 2):

I don't think サブラ is a common noun. This should usually mean "You mean Watanabe-san *of Sabra*?" where Sabra is the name of a shop or company.